# How to detect one of remote user in group call internet get disconnected joined through peerjs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, peerjs

How to detect any of member in group call internet gets disconnect.

```
    const checkPeerConnection = async () => {
    // console.log('checkPeerConnection', id, peer);
    try {
      const connection = await peer.connect(id);
      
      // const connection = await peer.getConnection(id, peer.connectionId);
      // console.log('connection', connection);

      connection.on('open', () => {
        // console.log(' open');
        setConnectionStatus('Connected');
      });

      connection.on('close', () => {
        // console.log(' close error');
        setConnectionStatus('Connection Closed');
      });

      connection.on('disconnected', () => {
        // console.log(' disconnected error');
        setConnectionStatus('Disconnected');
      });

      connection.on('error', (err) => {
        // console.log(' error error');
        setConnectionStatus('Error');
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(' catch error');
      setConnectionStatus('Error');
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      checkPeerConnection();
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

None of event is trigger on internet disconnect on remote users device.I want to show remote users that one of the user has internet problem.